# Коробить, коробиться — при чем тут коробка?

Tags: этимология

Когда хотят сказать, им что-то неприятно слышать, говорят "меня коробит..." Когда говорят о том, что предмет деформировался, употребляют "он покоробился".
А при чем тут коробка?

Answer (score 3):

Значение слова Коробить по Ефремовой:
Коробить - 1. Делать неровным, искривленным.
2. разг. Сводить судорогами. // перен. Производить неприятное, отталкивающее впечатление.

Значение слова Коробить по Ожегову:
Коробить - Вызывать неприятное чувство, внушать отвращениеКоробить Кривить, делать погнутым

Значение слова Коробить по словарю Ушакова:
КОРОБИТЬ
короблю, коробишь, чаще безл., несов. (к покоробить). 1. что. Делать неровным, искривленным. Доски коробит от сырости. 2. перен., кого-что. Производить неприятное, отталкивающее впечатление (разг.). Меня коробит от Его грубостей. Его поведение коробило всех.

Думаю, это слово происходит не от *коробка*, а от *короб.*
Короб изготавливали сгибанием бересты с последующим её прошиванием. Благодаря чему береста принимала несвойственную ей в природе форму.
Близкое значение имеет глагол *корёжить* от *коряга.*